# In which case is $\int_a^b f(x) dx \simeq f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) (b-a) $ a good approximation?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, numerical-calculus

I was wondering as I stated in the question title in which case is
$$\int_a^b f(x) dx \simeq f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) (b-a) $$ a good approximation.

As I can see it depends on the $f(x)$ and also on the integration interval chosen, and I doubt that there is a general rule about it, but there are particular cases (e.g the function is a well known function as the gaussian, there are particular symmetries etc.) in which the approximation is good ? (with good I intend that we can estimate the error commited).
And also, there is a rule of thumb in which one can use this approximation not commiting such big error ?

Comment: Please clearly state what you mean by *good approximation*.

Comment: The error can be estimated by the maximum absolute value of the second derivate in the interval.

Comment: See "Error Analysis” in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule

Comment: @MartinR And if the function is convex or concave on $I=[a,b]$ we get the result no ?

Comment: A tangential remark that may be worth noting that if $f$ is continuous on $\left[a,b\right]$, then there is always a point $c\in \left(a,b\right)$ such that $\int_{a}^{b} f\left(x\right)dx = f\left(c\right)\left(b-a\right)$. (The statement follows from the mean value theorem applied to the function $g\left(t\right) = \int_{a}^{t} f\left(x\right)dx$ on $\left[a,b\right]$.) In a sense, you are asking how good of an approximation the midpoint of the interval is in the context of the mean value theorem.

Comment: By https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Midpoint_rule $$
\left| {\int_a^b {f(x)dx}  - f\left( {\frac{{a + b}}{2}} \right)(b - a)} \right| \le \mathop {\sup }\limits_{a \le x \le b} \left| {f''(x)} \right|\frac{{(b - a)^3 }}{{24}}.
$$ So you would like $f''(x)$ to be small throughout the interval.

Comment: @Gary I think I can easily construct the case where f''(x) behaves any way you want and still to get to the required result. So this formula of yours is only a sufficient condition and really does not resolve the situation much. I am saying that even of f''(x) is huge, the result could be still valid.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is rather simple: when the average value of $f(x)$ in the interval is close to $f(\frac{a+b}{2})$

$$\bar{f}(x) \Big | _a^b=\frac1{b-a}\int_a^b f(x) dx \simeq f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)$$

Regarding the symmetry, the integrating behavior to the left and to the right of the central point are canceling up to the median value. Other than that it is difficult to say anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give a derivation of the asymptotic error. Without loss of generality, we can assume $a = -h$ and $b = h$ for some $h > 0$. Suppose $f \in C^4([-h, h])$. For any function $g$, let $E(g) = g(0) \cdot 2h - \int_{-h}^{h}g(x)\,dx$, the error of the approximation on $g$. By Taylor's theorem,
$$f = f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{f''(0)}{2}x^2 + \frac{f^{(3)}(0)}{3!}x^3 + \frac{f^{(4)}(c(x))}{4!}x^4.$$
By direct computation, $E(1) = E(x) = E(x^3) = 0$. By linearity of $E$,
$$E(f) = f(0)E(1) + f'(0)E(x) + \frac{f''(0)}{2}E(x^2) + \frac{f^{(3)}(0)}{3!}E(x^3) + E(\frac{f^{(4)}(c(x))}{4!}x^4) = \frac{f''(0)}{2}E(x^2) + O(h^5).$$
By direct computation, $E(x^2) = \frac{2}{3}h^3$. Thus
$$E(f) = \frac{f''(0)}{3}h^3 + O(h^5) = \frac{f''(0)}{24}(b - a)^3 + O((b - a)^5).$$